# list all combinations from combinatoric

Tags: python

Let's say there are **3 sets with 2 elements** in each set and I want to take one element from each set.

I know that there is `2^3 = 8` total combinations possible, what would be an efficient algorithm in python to list all the possible combinations?

Answer (score 0):

Simple! The [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) will give you the cartesian product of the parameters.

```
from itertools import product
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
c = [5, 6]
for combo in product(a, b, c):
    print(combo)
```

Output:

```
(1, 3, 5)
(1, 3, 6)
(1, 4, 5)
(1, 4, 6)
(2, 3, 5)
(2, 3, 6)
(2, 4, 5)
(2, 4, 6)
```

Here is the source for itertools.product

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

Keep in mind that this returns an iterable generator meaning if you want to store these somewhere, you will need to convert it to a list. If you only need it once, don't bother.